# Is USB Vendor ID needed to sell custom USB-hub based on IC?

Tags: usb, usb-device, legal

*I'm about to make a hobby project - build custom USB hub fitting required physical/package dimensions and port positions. The main IC would be TI TUSB4041I, which is is 4-port 2.0 USB HUB (I don't dare to go to USB 3.0 level with my very limited skills).*

*After a successful prototype, I 'm considering to have the device upgraded to 3.0, and manufactured professionally, in some higher quantity, and to sell it.*

If I was about to sell custom USB hub device, which is based on IC like TI TUSB4041I, then do I need to register custom Vendor ID?

1. would it be legal to sell device without Vendor ID and Product ID?
2. would it be functional? (I guess yes, as it depends on device class, subclass, and protocol)

Answer (score 3):

The TI TUSB4041I IC comes with a pre-programmed vendor/product ID, namely 0x0451 / 0x8140.

According to the data sheet:

> The value **may** be overwritten to indicate a customer vendor/product ID.

My interpretation of the statement is that it's ok to leave it at the preprogrammed value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, that's good, that it has got a default vendor ID and product ID. Whether this VID+PID can be used in final product, I will still need to clarify. However, I wouldn't like to have this question IC specific. Actually, I'm considering to switch to other IC, maybe FE1.1s. Because TI TUSB4041I IC is quite expensive.

Comment: However, I'm getting feeling, that it might be legal to sell products based on IC. If IC has got default/stock VID and PID, and manufacturer allows it, then I can sell such products. If IC hasn't got stock VID and PID, then I need to acquire VID and PID in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need your own VID - for devices, often the manufacturer of the USB IC you're using will sell you one or more PIDs in their VID space for a very reasonable price. Alternatively, especially for fixed-function devices they may allow you to use their "stock" VID/PID. I would expect a hub with exposed downstream ports to fall into that category, but you'd have to ask TI or see if they have a published policy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer showing possible ways to obtain/use Vendor ID. I'll definitely explore those ways once I finish the prototype. However, the provided answer doesn't give an answer the original question: do I need to obtain somehow vendor ID, and what happens if I don't obtain vendor id? (maybe I didn't phrase myself correctly there)